# What is the primary purpose of the prefrontal cortex?

Tags: neuroscience

I've heard of many functions of the prefrontal cortex (e.g. creativity, working memory, abstract thought, inhibition, planning, executive function, etc...).

But I'd like to know what its primary function is? For example is there any one function it has which facilitates all of its other functions? Or is there a known reason why it evolved in the first place?

Comment: Sorry for being such a downer on your last couple questions here, but first "What do you think?" is kind of a flag for the opinion-based questions that are not a good fit for the StackExchange format and are usually voted to be closed. Second, why should there be a one-sentence answer to this question? "Prefrontal cortex" is just a geometric label for a region of the brain, and a pretty arbitrary one at that: it includes **14** different Brodmann areas, and Brodmann areas need not themselves even have a one-sentence function.

Comment: I can re-word it but I'm not asking an opinion. I'm asking for science's best approximation of an abstract fact. The reason I'm asking is because information concerning the prefrontal cortex seems a little bit disconnected & sometimes inconsistent.

Comment: I'd certainly expect you to get disconnected and inconsistent answers to "what's the one sentence summary of what prefrontal cortex does" because there could be so many and also because most of how the brain works at a high level of organization is not currently understood.

Comment: I just want to know what the most fundamental function it serves is.

Comment: I don't think that's a factually answerable question any more than "what is the most fundamental sandwich".

Comment: Alright... I reworded it so it is more clear what I'm asking. And also clear how the answer is not an opinion.

Comment: "To facilitate an organism's survival until it can attain reproductive success and enough to facilitate reproductive success of it's offspring in a varied and challenging environment." - What more than that are you after?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer which is as simple as possible, while still being specific enough (i.e. unique to the prefrontal cortex & without ambiguous meaning), and abstract enough (i.e. able to generalize the usual 'laundry list' of functionality people attribute to it).

Comment: Attributing purpose to the prefrontal cortex (or really to any biological part) is really the wrong way to look at things.  Ask instead what it does, how it started to evolve in the first place, how it gave the possessors of early versions an evolutionary advantage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the function of the prefrontal cortex boiled down to a single coarse approximation, the answer is [executive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefrontal_cortex#Executive_function).  That notion of more structured and symbolic cognition encompasses pretty much all of the others on your laundry list.

As with other complex and multifunctional organs in the body, reducing the prefrontal cortex in this manner is a problematic oversimplification, in much the same way as describing the function of the mouth as "getting things in and out of the body".

Comment: hm ok fair enough

Answer (score 0):

This brain region's primary activity is orchestration of thoughts, actions, in accordance to internal goals. [Many authors](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29275839/) have suggested a link between personality and functions of the prefrontal cortex.

This brain region is involved in executive functions such as planning and decision-making, personality expression, moderation of speech and language, controlling certain aspects of speech, and language.

Comment: This also looks like it could become a good answer, but in addition to what I said on your other post this is a poor question because it is opinion based (see comments), which is why it has multiple downvotes. Please consider deleting this post as it is encouraging the posting of questions that are not appropriate for this site — from [How do I write a good answer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`*